# Internal Anchors not Working in fixed parallel website

Tags: jquery, html, css

Trying to scroll down on click

```
  <a href="#scrollto" id="scroll"> <div class="arrow-down"><img class="arrow-open" src="assets/img/arrow-sm.png"></div><a/>
```

to

```
 <p id="scrollto">MadHouse is a collective of strategists, advisors, innovators, creative thinkers, doers, makers, prodders, provocateurs, and believers committed to helping organizations Broaden their Biases.</p>
```

But its not working.

Tried Javascript

```
$("#scrollto").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

not working either.

[URL Working on](http://test.madhouseinc.com/beta7/) :

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong id for scroll,

Try this

```
$("#scroll").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

You are setting click on `#scrollto` instead of `#scroll`

Comment: in your website the structure is wrong, so click is not working. your scrollto p tag is above the click a href

Comment: No anchor is b before P

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and you're all set...

```
$("img.arrow-open").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('section.background:first-child').addClass('down-scroll');
});
```

Comment: There is no such code on your page, i think you have not updated the code i gave here...By the way it's still working if you put above code in console...Please check...

Comment: Still i am not able to find above script on your page...Please make sure it's there... And i am 100% sure that it will work, because i have tried it in console...